# Get user username and uuid

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a question, how can I get username and uuid in template?

Views

```
join_count = list(Profile.objects.all().aggregate(Max('join_count')).values())[0]
```

Model

```
class Profile(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
rank = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Gracz', choices=RANK_CHOICES)
buy_rank = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
join_count = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
money = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
money_is = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
kills = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
deaths = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

How to enable access to uuid and username via `join_count`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query :

```
Profile.objects.all().order_by('join_count').last()
```

Comment: I now about it, but i want get acces to username and uuid from user where join_count  = list(Profile.objects.all().aggregate(Max('join_count')).values())[0] . This get max value from Profile and it model Profile have field user, and how get value user.username

Comment: @Tshibe Use this query Profile.objects.all().order_by('join_count').last() it gives you a profile record with maximum join_count value

Comment: Ok, it working perfectly I got the brainbone for such an obvious thing

Comment: @Tshibe I changed my answer